# retrieving the elements from array whose elements are objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

i have two arrays variables in which each element is an object having some properties  like this :

```
var employees = [{
                 name: 'Jack',
                 empId: 0,
                 age: 25,
                 orgId: 1
                 }, {
                 name: 'Lucifer', 
                 empId: 1,
                 age: 35,
                 orgId: 2
                 }, {
                 name: 'Adam',
                 empId: 3,
                 age: 46,
                 orgId: 1
                 }, {
                 name: 'Eve',
                 empId: 4,
                 age: 30,
                 orgId: 3
               }];
```

and the second variable is

```
var companies= [{
 name: 'Microsoft',
 id: 1,
 employees: [5 , 9]
}, {
 name: 'Google',
 id: 2,
 employees: [1]
}, {
 name: 'LinkedIn',
 id: 3,
 employees: [10]
}];
```

so now i want that when i give a company name (for example: Google),then it will return the employee details. i want to do it by using filter()/reduce() method, but i am not able to do it . Help needed .. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the employee `orgId` is the same as the company `id` you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter); one to get the `id`, and then another to grab the employees associated with that id. The function returns an array of employees.

```
function getEmployees(company) {
  var id = companies.filter(function (el) {
      return el.name === company;
  })[0].id;
  return employee.filter(function (el) {
      return el.orgId === id;
  });
}

getEmployees('Microsoft');
```

OUTPUT

```
[
  {
    "name": "Jack",
    "empId": 0,
    "age": 25,
    "orgId": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Adam",
    "empId": 3,
    "age": 46,
    "orgId": 1
  }
]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/586z505x/)

Comment: That's a good answer with a good demonstration of using the filter method

Comment: @Andy can u please tell me why u have given [0].id in the first filter ??

Comment: `filter` returns an array. Because that filter is only going to return one element matching the company name we grab the first element `[0]` which is an object, and then `.id` to get the id which we use in the second filter. @amark

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a `forEach` loop and checking the name:

```
var Employees = []; //initialize  
companies.forEach(function(company) {
    if (company.name == "Microsoft"){
        Employees = company.employees;
        //whatever you like
        Employees.forEach(function(id){
              alert(id);
        });

    }
});
```

Working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sapyt777/

Comment: Be carefull with `.forEach()` method and its compatibility with IE8 and older browsers.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude good point, but lets hope most people do not use ie8 anymore ;)

Comment: I wish God hears you. And IE9 / IE10 we must to kill them too. Long live to standards.

Comment: You might want to check that answer. The first line is commented and there's at least one typo.

Comment: @Andy thanks ! I am typing on phone... not the best way to type code I know.

Comment: @BasvanStein Just wanted to bring your attention to the break; as it's not compatible with forEach loops.

Comment: @BasvanStein also this code will never work as you are iterating through the employee property of company not the employee var. so for this to work you have to iterate through the employee var or give a short answer by alert-ing only the id. as you don't have a reference to an employee object, so alert(id) will log the employee ids

Comment: @lKashef thanks, the employee array is provided by the question.

Comment: @BasvanStien why it is showing undefined in alerts ??

Comment: @amark, because the alert function parameter is employee[id]  when it must be only id to show the employee ids or loop again to access the employee with the right index. Assumig index 0 in the employee array is the right employee to show then we will alert(employee[0].id)

Comment: @BasvanStien I can see that but the index you are specifying doesn't correspond to the 0-based index of the employee obj in the employee array

Comment: As well as the code not working, [even if it did work](http://jsfiddle.net/su4xad31/1/) it would produce no result because there are no employees with ids equal to 5 or 9.

Comment: @Andy, you are right but is this a problem of the answer or of the question? I assume the id should be the same as the array index, if that is not the case it is not even possible to link them the way they are now. I updated my code though so it works.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to brush-up my skills. So I'm pretty sure it works but I don't know if it's a good way to achieve what you want!

```
var input = "Microsoft";

for(company in companies) {
    if(companies[company].name === input) {
        for(emp in employee) {
            if(companies[company].id === employee[emp].orgId)
            {
                console.log(employee[emp]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't go changing the names of variables in the question if answers referencing that variable have already been posted. It breaks the code in those answers.

Comment: It just made good sense but you are right! .. Thanks for the advice, I updated my answer but not sure if I can cancel my pending edit!

Comment: Don't worry - I had exactly the same thought.

Comment: i am a newbie to javascript never touched before so im getting confused in so many things

suppose if i made a function like this:
function emp(name,companies,employees){
     this.name = name;
     this.companies = companies;
     this.employee = employees;
}
now i create a object from the above function like :

var emp1 = new emp('Microsoft',companies,emplyees);

now i given the company name like this, then how to get the all employees for this

Comment: @amark my advice to you don't use 'this' for now as it a bit complicated and it's better to gain more ground before using it. I suggest you attend a couple of javascript courses in Udacity they are free and the Object Oriented Java course explains the 'This' parameter in details. For now my code will return an array of JSONs in console which you can view by using developer tools in a browser. You can post more details about the mark-up/HTML as well so we can better help with a more complete solution.

Comment: @lKashef, I would be wary of [using `for...in` loops for arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

Comment: @Andy Can you please explain why

Comment: It's all explained in the link. Mostly it's not a problem, but it can throw a couple of gotchas if you're not careful which is why it's not considered good practice.

Comment: @Andy, but if I add a hasOwnProperty check I think it will be safe and ignoring the unassigned index is not bad in this case as it won't find anything, right ? .. Just making sure taking advantage of this question's example

Comment: @amark, yes it can and based on Andy's link it looks like a better and more safe option